# What is the intrinsicMatrix for an iPhone X rear camera?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, ios12, iphone-x

I'm looking for the camera Calibration Matrix from an iPhone X (but I don't have one to use).

[image]

Hoping someone has done enough iOS with ARKit to help me out with this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Richard Berwick, Were you able to figure the intrinsicMatrix for an iPhone X rear camera?

Answer (score 0):

Each camera is different so you should calibrate your own. Print out a chessboard and checkout the [opencv tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html).
That said, they are more or less the same. So there you go, use it with precaution:

```
# --- Calibrated using iPhone X at video mode with resolution @ 1920x1080 ---
# K
[[1.97547873e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 1.06077279e+03],
 [0.00000000e+00, 2.05341424e+03, 5.13500761e+02],
 [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]]
# dist
[ 0.37367123, -1.29505304, -0.01482113,  0.01368264,  0.92461805]

# --- Calibrated using iPhone X at photo mode with resolution @ 3024x4032 ---
# K
[[3.20512987e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 1.99443897e+03],
 [0.00000000e+00, 3.17391061e+03, 1.41309060e+03],
 [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]]
# dist
[4.189866e-01, -3.496832e+00, -1.239132e-02, -1.649367e-03, 1.055315e+01]
```